# Resaltar errores en tiempo real de PHP en Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, vscode

Hasta ahora usaba para PHP NetBeans que automáticamente y en tiempo real me informaba de errores y warnings en el proyecto resaltandolo con un subrallado en el editor de texto, acabo de mirar a Visual Studio Code y no se me marcan errores, por lo que si  e me escapa algún punto y coma o cualquier tontearía tengo que revisar bien el código por que el programa no me lo indica, ¿De que manera VSC puede informarme en tiempo real de errores PHP?
Gracias

Comment: Acabas de añadirlo ?? y agregaste las extensiones de los lenguajes que usas ?? Por ejemplo, para PHP yo uso PHP Intelephense

Comment: Visual Studio Code ya tiene algo así, es [PHP Intelisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client). Aunque solamente detecta si las variables no están siendo usadas y detecta si escribieste algo mal (Saltarte la ; por ejemplo, o te falto un [ o un (, entre otros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para Visual Studio Code, existen las extensiones dedicadas a cada lenguaje.
En tu caso, recomendaría añadir `PHP Inteliphense`.
Para ello, dirigete a tus extensiones (ctrl+mayus+X)
Y buscas por nombre "PHP Intelephense"
Instalas y recargas visual studio y listo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

puedes instalarte SonarLint, es una extensión muy útil y ayuda con varios lenguajes de programación entre estos php. La instalas estando en VSC oprimes CTRL+SHIFT+X y buscas sonarlint. saludos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]